# Using reflection to get methods of different classes with same name?

Tags: php, class, reflection, methods

I have 2 classes with the same name located in different module. When using reflection to get methods for classes, it only finds the 1st one and its methods. How to specify whether to find class to reflect at another module (another folder)?

Comment: @KennyTM it's in PHP language

Comment: silentbang: Please provide the `php` tag in the future.

Comment: thanks for your recommendation

Answer (score 1):

consider using namespaces to avoid name collisions.

`/application/moduleA/myclassname`

`/application/moduleB/myclassname`

or attach a prefix to your classname.

`moduleA_myclassname`

`moduleB_myclassname`

Answer (score 0):

Simply specify the full qualified name.